# Prove a conditional distribution is uniformly distributed across a given interval?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables identically exponentially distributed with $\lambda$. Take $Z=X+Y$.

Show that $(X|Z=z)$ is uniformly distributed over $(0<x<z)$.

Then, find $$E[X^k|Z=z]$$.

---

I need help getting started.

$$P[X|Z=z] = \frac{P[X, Z=z]}{P[Z=z]}$$
$$= \frac{({\lambda e^{-\lambda x}})({\lambda e^{-\lambda y}}+\lambda e^{-\lambda x})}{({\lambda e^{-\lambda y}}+\lambda e^{-\lambda x})}$$
Is that right?
I'm sort of confused on the conditional probability, because this would simply to just $P[X]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, exponential distributions are continuous, which means you're dealing with probability densities rather than masses.  $$f_X(x)=\lambda~\mathsf e^{-\lambda x}~\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;\infty)}\textrm{ and }f_Y(y)\textrm{ likewise.}$$

Secondly $Z=X+Y$ so $f_{X, Z}(x, z) = f_X(x)~f_Y(z-x)$ and $f_Z(z) = \int_\Bbb R f_X(x)~f_Y(z-x)\operatorname d x$

Thusly:
$$\begin{align}
f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z) & = \dfrac{f_X(x)~f_Y(z-x)}{\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R f_X(x)~f_Y(z-x)~\operatorname d x}~\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq z} \\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\lambda^2~\mathsf e^{-\lambda x}~\mathsf e^{-\lambda (z-x)}}{\displaystyle\int_0^z \lambda^2~\mathsf e^{-\lambda x}~\mathsf e^{-\lambda (z-x)}\operatorname d x}~\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq z}
\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 z~\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq z}
\end{align}$$

Thus $X\mid Z=z \sim \mathcal U(0;z)$

---

Now use this to find $\mathsf E(X^k\mid Z=z) = \int_0^z x^k~f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z)\operatorname d x$